# Shading after bevel

Tags: shaders, bevel

Need Your help, please!
I applied boolean to my model, thus I received cuts I need.
However, when I applying bevel to the edges of the panel, where I did a cut, then I get strange shading issue. And I get it only, when bevel segments are more than 1.
Link to a file: https://pasteall.org/blend/2b84e6a21a8143d49719b14a51e545fd

[image: Before beveling]

[image: After beveling]

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: hello please share your file so that we try to find the best way to fix it: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello! Here it is https://pasteall.org/blend/2b84e6a21a8143d49719b14a51e545fd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender tries to smooth between the large faces and the first bevel faces ring, therefore this artefact. What you can do is select the faces, inset (as image below), then bevel. This way the faces are coplanar with the next ones and the artefact is not visible anymore:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, but then I'm loosing a bevel effect... Is there a way to make it more beatiful?

Comment: so inset before the bevel

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Check *Autosmooth* to get consistent shading areas.
When using *Bevel*, check *Harden Normals* to keep correct shading.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm using "manual" bevel, not a modifier, as not all of edges require beveling. Anyways, thanks for good advise!
P.S.: Just found a tick box in the manual bevel dialog window. WIll try it as well

Comment: No prob ;) I can wholeheartedly recommend the bevel modifier tho - you can limit bevel by weight or angle and adjust it any time. Really useful for hardsurface modeling.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is how i did it
blend file work address：https://pasteall.org/media/0/7/0729e9f70685d1a8d3d7aac79617e94d.blend
After adding the chamfer modifier, there is no problem